# Go To Next Scene

Tags: actionscript-3, button, addition, flash-cs6

im adding button, name "button 1" this button appear at the end of the scene 1.this button link to the next scene which is the scene 2.
my point here is to go next scene which is "scene 2",frame 1
why is it its keep coming back to the start instead in the next scene.. here my codes.

```
    Button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextScene);

function fl_ClickToGoToNextScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).nextScene();
}
```

where i got wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1,"NextSceneName");
```

Also if you are at the last frame of your first scene you may also try `nextFrame();`